# How do I deploy a Three.js project to github pages?

Tags: javascript, html, deployment, three.js

I have recently been working on a personal portfolio website. For this project, I have decided to implement the Three.js library. I have downloaded this library locally on my laptop. Locally, the website runs as intended. I am now at the stage in which I want to deploy the code into github pages. I have tried to add the Three.js library to the repository, however, Github says that there are too many files to add. This causes the HTML and CSS to load properly, however, there is a white screen in place of the Three.js scene.

How do I add the library to the repository, or is this even possible? I have also seen some information regarding using a CDN instead of uploading the library. If this is the optimal solution, how should I go about implementing this?

Answer (score 2):

I found that using [gh-pages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages) is the easiest way to deploy a Three.js project to GitHub Pages. Here are the steps I take:

1. In the project's terminal, run `npm install gh-pages`
2. Under "scripts" in your package.json, add a script for 'deploy.' Like this: `"deploy": gh-pages -d dist`
3. Build your project (`npm run build`) & make sure you have your GitHub repo set up.
4. Now, you can run `npm run deploy` in the terminal, which will set up your project in Git Hub Pages.

Running `npm run deploy` automatically creates a branch called gh-pages. It also automatically sets up your GitHub Pages settings to reference this branch.

[Here is a Loom video](https://www.loom.com/share/1d9a06ec11f542e5861ef7e85e38e912) of me successfully deploying a new Three.js project to GitHub pages. I go through each of the steps I listed above. You may also reference my repo [here](https://github.com/jessachalla/threejs-scroller-gh-pages-demo).

I don't know if this helps with the issue about Github saying there are too many files to add. Let me know if that is still a problem after taking these steps.

Here is another article I referenced:
[Publishing a Three.js Project on GitHub Pages](https://hackernoon.com/publishing-a-threejs-project-on-github-pages-1d1a33dn)